# Mediawiki can't load CSS if SSL is enabled

Tags: ssl, mediawiki

There is an `http://` hardcoded somewhere in mediawiki codebase, causing these errors. Can't find out, what.

```
Index:13 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xy/Index' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://xy/load.php?debug=false&lang=hu&modules=mediawiki.legacy.co…face%7Cmediawiki.ui.button%7Cskins.vector.styles&only=styles&skin=vector&*'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Index:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xy/Index' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://xy/load.php?debug=false&lang=hu&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&*'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Did you search the code base? For either `http://` or maybe `load.php`

Comment: grep found 10k+, this is a huge codebase and I'm looking for a needle. (load.php doesn't contain this exact word)

Comment: Maybe  `http://(up to 20 characters)/load.php?`... but I don't know Mediawiki that well

Comment: What MW version? I don't think this should normally be a problem. Did you try setting `$wgServer` manually in `LocalSettings.php`, to override the automatic detection.

Comment: There it is with http:. Thanks, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

In your mediawiki folder, there's a file named LocalSettings.php

You need to edit that file and change $wgServer value from http:// to https://